# Attribute null values

Tags: php, magento2

I am trying to simply find out if an attribute has a value and this code no longer seems to work.  I'm using magento 2.10

```
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('bullet_3'); 
if ($attribute) 
{ 
    $attr_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
    if ($attr_value===NULL) {  }
    else {
    echo "<li>" . $attr_value . "</li>"; 
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any specific errors that could help point us to the issue?

Comment: I'm not getting an error but it is printing "No" if the attribute is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code like below.

```
if (!$_product->hasData('bullet_3') || (string)$attr_value == '') {

} else {
   echo "<li>" . $attr_value . "</li>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using if ($_product->hasData('bullet_3') { do something } and it worked.   I'm not sure why it prints No if the attribute is empty.